# IP Geocode using PHP echo

Tags: php, forms, input, ip, geocode

I'm trying to display the users country (based on their IP) in a form input value.

Here's my code so far ..

```
<input style="display:block" type="text" name="country" id="country" value="<?php               
$pageContent = file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.net/json/echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']');
$parsedJson  = json_decode($pageContent);
echo $parsedJson->country_name; ?>" />
```

I'm using PHP JSON-decode to get the data from "http://freegeoip.net/json/(IP ADDRESS)".

That website geocodes the IP address and returns a country name.

What I want to do is to be able to substitute in a users IP address into that web address, which would then return the country name of the user. The best way I could think of was by using

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>
```

but when I put it in I get a Server Error.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: No offence, but please do a bit of studying on basic PHP syntax...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$pageContent = file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.net/json/' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

You can't use `echo` within a function. Instead, you should use the [concatenating operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Also, better code would be something like this:

```
<?php               
$pageContent = file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.net/json/' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$parsedJson  = json_decode($pageContent);
?>
<input style="display:block" type="text" name="country" id="country" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($parsedJson->country_name); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$pageContent = file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.net/json/' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

No need to echo into a string parameter... just concatenate with `.`.

Answer (score 1):

I've been needing the `GeoIP`services myself in some project lately.
I've created a ** `PHP wrapper`**, in case others are looking for a `PHP` helper for this.

Can be found at https://github.com/DaanDeSmedt/FreeGeoIp-PHP-Wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Since Freegeoip will became a paid service (https://ipstack.com/), if you want a free simple service you can use ip-api.com instead of freegeoip.net :

```
function getDataOfIp($ip) {
    try {
        $pageContent = file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/' . $ip);
        $parsedJson  = json_decode($pageContent);
        return [
            "country_name" => $parsedJson->country,
            "country_code" => $parsedJson->countryCode,
            "time_zone" => $parsedJson->timezone
        ];
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You should adapt return value by the data you need.